# Масштабирование Яндекс карты

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Друзья, не могу разобраться и прошу помощи у Вас. Начну с кода (возможно, так будет правильно).

Подскажите, какую функцию нужно добавить чтобы карта самостоятельно определяла масштаб где будут видны все метки карты ? Если нужна ещё какая-то информация пишите, я добавлю что требуется.

````
function allPlacemarks() {
var myMap = new ymaps.Map('allPlacemarks', { // ID блока с картой
center: [55.76, 37.64], // Москва
zoom: 12,
controls: ['zoomControl', 'fullscreenControl']
},{
suppressMapOpenBlock: true, 
yandexMapDisablePoiInteractivity: true
}),
objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
// Чтобы метки начали кластеризоваться, выставляем опцию.
clusterize: true,
// ObjectManager принимает те же опции, что и кластеризатор.
gridSize: 32
});

//отключаем зум колёсиком мышки
myMap.behaviors.disable('scrollZoom');

//на мобильных устройствах... (проверяем по userAgent браузера)
//if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
//... отключаем перетаскивание карты
//myMap.behaviors.disable('drag');
//}

// Задаём опции кластеров
objectManager.clusters.options.set({
// Установим дизайн метки по умолчанию:
preset: 'islands#blueClusterIcons',
// Установим балун кластера в виде карусели для удобства
balloonContentLayout: 'cluster#balloonCarousel',
// Устанавливаем максимальное количество элементов в нижней панели на одной странице
clusterBalloonPagerSize: 5,
// Устанавливаем режим открытия балуна. 
// В данном примере балун никогда не будет открываться в режиме панели.
clusterBalloonPanelMaxMapArea: 0,
// Устанавливаем ширину макета контента балуна.
balloonContentLayoutWidth: 400,
// Устанавливаем высоту макета контента балуна.
balloonContentLayoutHeight: 300
});

// Подрубаем монитор, 
// будем отслеживать изменения в кластерах
var activeObjectMonitor = new ymaps.Monitor(objectManager.clusters.state);

// При клике на некластеризованные объекты получаем содержимое балуна
objectManager.objects.events.add('click', function (e) {
var objectId = e.get('objectId');
setBalloonData(objectId);
});

// В кластеризованных объектах отслеживаем изменение выбранного объекта
activeObjectMonitor.add('activeObject', function () {
var objectId = activeObjectMonitor.get('activeObject').id;
setBalloonData(objectId);
});

// Проверяем, есть ли у выбранного объекта содержимое балуна
function hasBalloonData(objectId) {
return objectManager.objects.getById(objectId).properties.balloonContent;
}

// Получаем данные и устанавливаем содержимое балуна
function setBalloonData(objectId) {
if (!hasBalloonData(objectId)) {
getBalloonData(objectId).done(function (data) {
var object = objectManager.objects.getById(objectId);
object.properties.balloonContent = data;
// Открываем балун на этом элементе
var objectState = objectManager.getObjectState(objectId);
if (objectState.isClustered) {
// Если это кластер
objectManager.clusters.balloon.open(objectState.cluster.id);
}
else {
// Если обычный объект
objectManager.objects.balloon.open(objectId);
}
});
}
}

// Добавляем objectManager на карту
myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);

// Выполняем ajax-запрос к мини-модулю для вывода всех меток 
$.ajax({
url: dle_root + 'engine/ajax/controller.php',
//url: dle_root + 'engine/ajax/ymaps/all.php',
dataType: 'json',
data: {
mod: 'ymaps_all',
// вместо allplacemarks можно прописать имя другого шаблона, содержащего в себе конфигурацию для вывода меток
// сам шаблон с конфигом находится в папке ymaps/all
preset: 'ajaxmap'
},
})
.done(function (data) {
// Если всё ок - добавим метки на карту
objectManager.add(data);

// "Отключим" прелодер.
$('#allPlacemarks').removeClass('loader');


// Выплюнем в консольку данные, пришедшие от модуля:
// console.log(data);

// Эти переменные нужны для дальнейшего показа количества видимых на карте меток.
var singleCounter = 0,
singleCounterHidden = 0,
clusterCounter = 0;

// Пример организации обхода массива видимых меток
objectManager.objects.each(function (object) {
// В данный момент нас интересует конкретный геообъект
var objectState = objectManager.getObjectState(object.id);
if (objectState.isClustered) {
// Если метка геообъекта находится в составе кластера - прибавим счётчик.
clusterCounter++;
}
else {
// Если метка не в кластере прибавим другой счётчик.
singleCounterHidden++;
if (objectState.isShown) {
// Если метка не в кластере и показана в области
// видимости карты - прибавим другой счётчик и
// убавим счётчик всех объектов. Таким образом счётчик будет
// показывать только скрытые объекты
singleCounter++;
singleCounterHidden--;
}
}
}, myMap);

// Ну и теперь можно выплюнуть собранные счётчики в консоль:
console.log('Количество показаных единичных меток: ' + singleCounter);
console.log('Количество невидимых единичных меток: ' + singleCounterHidden);
console.log('Количество показаных меток, составе кластера: ' + clusterCounter);

})
.fail(function () {
console.log("error");
});

// Функция, осуществляющая запрос за данными балуна на сервер.
function getBalloonData(objectId) {
var dataDeferred = ymaps.vow.defer();

// Для получения новости используется модуль {AJAX FULL-STORY}:
// http://pafnuty.name/modules/156-ajax-full-story.html
$.ajax({
url: dle_root + 'engine/ajax/full-story.php',
type: 'GET',
dataType: 'html',
data: {
newsId: objectId, // Обязательная переменная
template: 'ajax/baloon'
},
})
.done(function (data) {
dataDeferred.resolve(data);
})
.fail(function () {
console.log("full-story error");
dataDeferred.resolve('error');
});

return dataDeferred.promise();
}
}```
````

Comment: И так, думаю я на правильном пути. 
myMap.setBounds(myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager).getBounds(), {checkZoomRange: true});

Осталось разобраться с зумом. Очень близко приближает. Жду подсказки от Вас.

Comment: И с зумом всё хорошо. 
myMap.setBounds(myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager).getBounds(), {checkZoomRange:true}).then(function(){ if(myMap.getZoom() > 10) myMap.setZoom(10);});

Answer (score 1):

Весь код. Работает, ошибок не выявлено. Возможно кому-то понадобится.

````
function allPlacemarks() {
var myMap = new ymaps.Map('allPlacemarks', { // ID блока с картой
center: [55.76, 37.64], // Москва
zoom: 12,
controls: ['zoomControl', 'fullscreenControl']
},{
suppressMapOpenBlock: true, 
yandexMapDisablePoiInteractivity: true
}),
objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
// Чтобы метки начали кластеризоваться, выставляем опцию.
clusterize: true,
// ObjectManager принимает те же опции, что и кластеризатор.
gridSize: 32
});

//отключаем зум колёсиком мышки
myMap.behaviors.disable('scrollZoom');

// Задаём опции кластеров
objectManager.clusters.options.set({
// Установим дизайн метки по умолчанию:
preset: 'islands#blueClusterIcons',
// Установим балун кластера в виде карусели для удобства
balloonContentLayout: 'cluster#balloonCarousel',
// Устанавливаем максимальное количество элементов в нижней панели на одной странице
clusterBalloonPagerSize: 5,
// Устанавливаем режим открытия балуна. 
// В данном примере балун никогда не будет открываться в режиме панели.
clusterBalloonPanelMaxMapArea: 0,
// Устанавливаем ширину макета контента балуна.
balloonContentLayoutWidth: 400,
// Устанавливаем высоту макета контента балуна.
balloonContentLayoutHeight: 300
});

// Подрубаем монитор, 
// будем отслеживать изменения в кластерах
var activeObjectMonitor = new ymaps.Monitor(objectManager.clusters.state);

// При клике на некластеризованные объекты получаем содержимое балуна
objectManager.objects.events.add('click', function (e) {
var objectId = e.get('objectId');
setBalloonData(objectId);
});

// В кластеризованных объектах отслеживаем изменение выбранного объекта
activeObjectMonitor.add('activeObject', function () {
var objectId = activeObjectMonitor.get('activeObject').id;
setBalloonData(objectId);
});

// Проверяем, есть ли у выбранного объекта содержимое балуна
function hasBalloonData(objectId) {
return objectManager.objects.getById(objectId).properties.balloonContent;
}

// Получаем данные и устанавливаем содержимое балуна
function setBalloonData(objectId) {
if (!hasBalloonData(objectId)) {
getBalloonData(objectId).done(function (data) {
var object = objectManager.objects.getById(objectId);
object.properties.balloonContent = data;
// Открываем балун на этом элементе
var objectState = objectManager.getObjectState(objectId);
if (objectState.isClustered) {
// Если это кластер
objectManager.clusters.balloon.open(objectState.cluster.id);
}
else {
// Если обычный объект
objectManager.objects.balloon.open(objectId);
}
});
}
}

// Добавляем objectManager на карту
myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);

// Выполняем ajax-запрос к мини-модулю для вывода всех меток 
$.ajax({
url: dle_root + 'engine/ajax/controller.php',
//url: dle_root + 'engine/ajax/ymaps/all.php',
dataType: 'json',
data: {
mod: 'ymaps_all',
// вместо allplacemarks можно прописать имя другого шаблона, содержащего в себе конфигурацию для вывода меток
// сам шаблон с конфигом находится в папке ymaps/all
preset: 'ajaxmap'
},
})
.done(function (data) {
// Если всё ок - добавим метки на карту
objectManager.add(data);

myMap.setBounds(myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager).getBounds(), {checkZoomRange:true}).then(function(){ if(myMap.getZoom() > 10) myMap.setZoom(10);});

// "Отключим" прелодер.
$('#allPlacemarks').removeClass('loader');

})
.fail(function () {
console.log("error");
});

// Функция, осуществляющая запрос за данными балуна на сервер.
function getBalloonData(objectId) {
var dataDeferred = ymaps.vow.defer();

// Для получения новости используется модуль {AJAX FULL-STORY}:
// http://pafnuty.name/modules/156-ajax-full-story.html
$.ajax({
url: dle_root + 'engine/ajax/full-story.php',
type: 'GET',
dataType: 'html',
data: {
newsId: objectId, // Обязательная переменная
template: 'ajax/baloon'
},
})
.done(function (data) {
dataDeferred.resolve(data);
})
.fail(function () {
console.log("full-story error");
dataDeferred.resolve('error');
});

return dataDeferred.promise();
}
} ```
````